# Justin TV API - Jquery / JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api, justin.tv

I was wondering if somebody could show me an example of how to use the Justin TV API. They have this [documentation](http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/REST_API_Documentation) and an 'example' on there along with [return values](http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/Returned_Objects) (Here's the [xml file](http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.xml?channel=dreamhacksc2)) but when I try to use it I don't under stand where it defines what channel it's pulling from. If I want to pull a channels summary - I tried this:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.justin.tv/stream/summary?channel=dreamhacksc2", function(a){alert(a.summary);});
```

but I keep getting Bad Origin errors. I've been trying to find examples online but haven't found anything solid. Can somebody work up an example of pulling something from a certain channel? I could probably work off it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be using the right url for the [summary](http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/Stream/summary) method and JSONP. Try this one:

```
http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/summary.json?channel=dreamhacksc2&jsonp=?
```

Like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/summary.json?channel=dreamhacksc2&jsonp=?', function(a) {
    alert(a.viewers_count);
});
```

Comment: Oh I have a question though. If I want to get things like `channel_url`which is under `stream/list` but it's under a inner node in the xml of `channel` - how would I get that? Is it on a url base or when I alert it out on an object base?
Oh I have a question though. If I want to get things like `channel_url` `stream/list` but it's under a inner node of `channel` - how would I get that? http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/Stream/list

Comment: Assuming you have used `http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=dreamhacksc2&jsonp=?`, you could then `alert(a[0].channel.channel_url);` which should give you `http://www.justin.tv/dreamhacksc2`.